# self.canvas.create_text dissappearing

Tags: python, tkinter

```py
from tkinter import *
 
class wigdet:
    def __init__(self):
        window = Tk()
        window.title("Buttons and Radio Buttons")

        frame1 = Frame(window)
        frame1.pack()
        self.v1 = IntVar()

        rb_red = Radiobutton(frame1, text="Red", fg="black", variable= self.v1, value = 1, command=self.process_radio_button)
        rb_yellow = Radiobutton(frame1, text="Yellow", fg="black", variable= self.v1, value = 2, command=self.process_radio_button)
        rb_white = Radiobutton(frame1, text="White", fg="black", variable= self.v1, value = 3, command=self.process_radio_button)
        rb_gray = Radiobutton(frame1, text="Gray", fg="black", variable= self.v1, value = 4, command=self.process_radio_button)
        rb_green = Radiobutton(frame1, text="Green", fg="black", variable= self.v1, value = 5, command=self.process_radio_button)

        rb_red.grid(row=0, column=0)
        rb_yellow.grid(row=0, column=1)
        rb_white.grid(row=0, column=2)
        rb_gray.grid(row=0, column=3)
        rb_green.grid(row=0, column=4)

        frame2 = Frame(window)
        frame2.pack()

        self.canvas = Canvas(frame2, width=400, height=100, bg="white")
        self.x1, self.y1 = (200, 50)
        self.canvas.create_text(self.x1,self.y1, fill="black",text="Welcome",font=("Arial"),tags="text")
        self.canvas.pack()
        
        frame3 = Frame(window)
        frame3.pack()

        bt_left = Button(frame3, text = "<=", fg = "black", command = self.process_left)
        bt_right = Button(frame3, text = "=>", fg = "black", command = self.process_right)
        
        bt_left.grid(row=2, column=0)
        bt_right.grid(row=2, column=1)

        window.mainloop()

    def process_radio_button(self):
        if (self.v1.get() == 1):
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,400, 100, fill="red")
            self.canvas.create_text(self.x1,self.y1,fill="black",text="Welcome",font=("Arial"),tags="text")
        
        elif (self.v1.get() == 2):
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,400, 100, fill="yellow")
            self.canvas.create_text(self.x1,self.y1,fill="black",text="Welcome",font=("Arial"),tags="text")

        elif (self.v1.get() == 3):
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,400, 100, fill="white")
            self.canvas.create_text(self.x1,self.y1,fill="black",text="Welcome",font=("Arial"),tags="text")
        
        elif (self.v1.get() == 4):
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,400, 100, fill="gray")
            self.canvas.create_text(self.x1,self.y1,fill="black",text="Welcome",font=("Arial"),tags="text")
        
        else:
            self.canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,400, 100, fill="green")
            self.canvas.create_text(self.x1,self.y1,fill="black",text="Welcome",font=("Arial"),tags="text")
        
    def process_left(self):
        self.canvas.delete("text")
        if self.x1>10:
            self.x1-=10
        if self.x1>60:
            self.x1-=10
            self.canvas.create_text(self.x1, self.y1, fill="black", tags="text")
        

    def process_right(self):
        self.canvas.delete("text")
        if self.x1 < 350:
            self.x1+=10
        if self.x1 < 400:
            self.x1+=10
            self.canvas.create_text(self.x1, self.y1, fill="black", tags="text")
    

wigdet()
```

I have two buttons where I am to move the text left and right. I also have 5 `Radiobutton`s that decide the background color. when i chose for example red, and then move the text left, the text disappears, but reappears slightly to the left when i hit the `Radiobutton` for red.

any simple solution?

Comment: provide a [mre], and I would really suggest naming `class`es with `CapitalCase` names (as per PEP 8) (also you can just inherit from `Tk` and not have to have a `root` because `self` would be the root)

Comment: call `self.canvas.create_text` only once, save the returned integer (which is the "object's" id) and then use `self.canvas.coords(self.text_id, x1, y1)` where `self.text_id` is the id of the created text and move the text with this, there is no need to create text hundreds of times and no need to delete it either (because you wouldn't be creating it so many times), similarly do with the rectangle

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is an improved version of the code (explanation in code comments):

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font


# inherit from frame for easier use
class MyWidget(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)

        # create the frame for radio buttons
        self.rb_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        # variable for radio buttons and set value to something already
        self.rb_var = tk.StringVar(value='white')
        # iterate over colors and place the radio buttons with the color
        # text and set `value=color`, that way `self.rb_var.get()`
        # will return the color
        for color in ('red', 'yellow', 'white', 'gray', 'green'):
            tk.Radiobutton(
                self.rb_frame, text=color.title(), value=color,
                variable=self.rb_var, command=self.color_select
            ).pack(side='left')

        # configure canvas stuff, set width and height
        self.c_w, self.c_h = 600, 500
        # get initial x position for text
        self.x = self.c_w // 2
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=self.c_w, height=self.c_h)
        # create rectangle on canvas and save its id
        self.rect = self.canvas.create_rectangle(
            0, 0, self.c_w, self.c_h, fill=self.rb_var.get(),
            outline=self.rb_var.get())
        # define the text to display
        self.text = 'Welcome!'
        # use a `font` so that later can measure the text width
        self.font = font.Font(family='Arial')
        # measure text width to allow for better collision detection with sides
        self.text_width = self.font.measure(self.text)
        # create the text and save the id
        self.canvas_text = self.canvas.create_text(
            self.x, self.c_h // 2, text=self.text, font=self.font)

        # create the frame where the left/right buttons will be
        self.btn_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        # create the buttons
        tk.Button(
            self.btn_frame, text='>>>', command=lambda: self.move('right')
        ).pack(side='right', fill='x', expand=True)
        tk.Button(
            self.btn_frame, text='<<<', command=lambda: self.move('left')
        ).pack(side='left', fill='x', expand=True)

        # place all the created frames
        self.rb_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.canvas.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.btn_frame.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='we')

    # the color selector method which is called from radio buttons
    def color_select(self):
        value = self.rb_var.get()
        # as you can see then using `value=color` earlier now this is possible
        # to easily set the color
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.rect, fill=value, outline=value)
    
    # method for moving
    def move(self, side):
        # get half width of font because the center of the created text is middle
        half_width = self.text_width // 2
        if side == 'left' and self.x - 10 - half_width > 0:
            self.x -= 10
        elif side == 'right' and self.x + 10 + half_width < self.c_w:
            self.x += 10
        # move the created text
        self.canvas.coords(self.canvas_text, self.x, self.c_h // 2)


# in general good practice to use this if statement
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create the root
    root = tk.Tk()
    
    # put the widget on the window
    frame = MyWidget(root)
    frame.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

As you see, there is no need to delete the created text or rectangles, just change their coordinates and options (which can be done with tags too, I just used IDs)

Also:
I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; name clashes are the issue.

I strongly suggest following [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Function and variable names should be in `snake_case`, class names in `CapitalCase`. Don't have space around `=` if it is used as a part of keyword argument (`func(arg='value')`) but have space around `=` if it is used for assigning a value (`variable = 'some value'`). Have space around operators (`+-/` etc.: `value = x + y`(except here `value += x + y`)). Have two blank lines around function and class declarations. Object method definitions have one blank line around them.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you delete existing text and create a new text object ***without assigning `text`*** to it.  So you just create a empty text object.

Also it is better to create those canvas items once and using `coords()` to move them and `itemconfig()` to change their attributes.

```py
class widget:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        # create the background rectangle first
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,400, 100, fill="white", tags="rect")
        self.canvas.create_text(self.x1,self.y1, fill="black",text="Welcome",font=("Arial"),tags="text")
        ...

    def process_radio_button(self):
        if (self.v1.get() == 1):
            fill="red"
        elif (self.v1.get() == 2):
            fill="yellow"
        elif (self.v1.get() == 3):
            fill="white"
        elif (self.v1.get() == 4):
            fill="gray"
        else:
            fill="green"

        # change the fill color
        self.canvas.itemconfig("rect", fill=fill)

    def process_left(self):
        # why two if ???
        if self.x1>10:
            self.x1-=10
        if self.x1>60:
            self.x1-=10
            # move the text
            self.canvas.coords("text", self.x1, self.y1)

    def process_right(self):
        # why two if ???
        if self.x1 < 350:
            self.x1+=10
        if self.x1 < 400:
            self.x1+=10
            # move the text
            self.canvas.coords("text", self.x1, self.y1)
```